# Ant Design - How to restrict clickable area of table headers when sorting

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-component

When we enable column sorting in the ant design tables, the whole column header will be clickable. But I want to reduce that clickable area only to the specific custom sorting icon in the header. Or else disable that column click behavior and trigger the sorting from a custom icon. Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom column header component via the `columns`'s `title` prop, where you can then create a custom icon to trigger manual sorting of the table's `dataSource` prop. See the following [CodeSandbox link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-custom-header-filter-checkbox-v9yhm?file=/index.js:0-2582)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, actually that's what exactly we are doing! the column you can see in the above screenshot is a custom column header component. The problem is I cannot figure out how to trigger sorting manually when clicking on the custom icon. I checked your sandbox link, but that functionality is not implemented in the provided example.

Comment: The sandbox example triggers filtering the table’s dataSource. You just need to change the logic to sort the dataSource array instead of filtering.

Comment: So you are suggesting re-write the sorting logic without reusing ant table built-in logic?

Comment: Yup. It's definitely not an ideal solution, and depending on how often you need this particular behavior it might not scale for your needs, but it will work. I would also suggest making use of lodash's sortBy method to keep the sorting logic clean (https://lodash.com/docs/#sortBy)

Answer (score 1):

wrap all the things inside a div/span which you dont want to be sorted when clicked on columnTitle , wrap then in title like this and add onclick which will stop event propagation so that it will not sort whatever inside this span/div when clicked

```
title : 
<span className='title'>Title</span>
<span onClick={(e)=>{e.stopPropagation();}}> {"things which you dont want to get affected by default column sorting in title"}</span>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).